# How to find Position of index in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
[33] => 
[53] => 
[82] => 
[36] => 
[47] => 
[42] => 
[1] => 
[12] => 
[86] => 
[68] => 
[31] => 1.00
[2] => 1.00
[87] => 2.00
[50] => 3.00
[10] => 3.00
[55] => 3.00
[48] => 3.00
[70] => 3.00
[90] => 3.00
[37] => 3.00
[69] => 3.00
[8] => 3.00
[49] => 3.00
[26] => 3.00
[13] => 3.00
[61] => 3.00
[59] => 3.00
[73] => 4.00
[64] => 4.00
[77] => 4.00
[78] => 4.00
[65] => 4.00
[66] => 4.00
[63] => 4.00
[76] => 4.00
[51] => 4.00
[52] => 4.00
[43] => 4.00
[58] => 4.00
[60] => 4.00
[74] => 4.00
[67] => 4.00
[35] => 4.00
[17] => 4.00
[16] => 4.00
[18] => 4.00
[20] => 4.00
[41] => 4.00
[15] => 4.00
[11] => 4.00
[4] => 4.00
[5] => 4.00
[6] => 4.00
[7] => 4.00
[83] => 4.00
[22] => 4.00
[34] => 4.00
[38] => 4.00
[40] => 4.00
[25] => 4.00
[32] => 4.00
[80] => 4.00
[81] => 4.00
[27] => 4.00
[30] => 4.00
[79] => 5.00
[89] => 5.00
[88] => 5.00
[72] => 5.00
[71] => 5.00
[44] => 5.00
[21] => 5.00
[23] => 5.00
[24] => 5.00
[19] => 5.00
[14] => 5.00
[3] => 5.00
[9] => 5.00
[28] => 5.00
[29] => 5.00
[56] => 5.00
[57] => 5.00
[54] => 5.00
[46] => 5.00
[39] => 5.00
[45] => 5.00
[62] => 5.00
)
```

Now what I want to find position of particular index. i.e if I search `53` then it returns its position i.e. `2`. As I'm considering `53` at `SECOND` position.

Comment: Wouldn't it return `1` since arrays are `0` indexed?

Comment: There is no association between `2` and `53` _anywhere_ :?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the keys with array_keys() and then try array_search() to get the index of it.

```
$keys = array_keys($yourArray);
$key = array_search('53', $keys);
```

didnt tested it but should work.

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
$a = array_keys($array)
```

to get an array that its values is the $array => keys

after that you can use

```
$a = array_flip($a);
```

to make the array values are the indexes of the array (**positions as you want!**)

then

```
$a["53"];//for example will get what you want
```

hope it helps

**Note :** if you are frequently accessing the $a use my way because it build the array and after that you'll have O(1) access time, if you need it for one or two access its better to use `array_search` to get the index from the `array_keys` array with O(n).

Answer (score 2):

```
function findIndex($arr, $needle) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
      if ($key === $needle) {
         return $i;
      }
      $i++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `$i++` should be after `if` because will return +1

Comment: @MihaiIorga Yep, the OP wants 2(which is a typo he said) at first.

Answer (score 1):

Get all array-keys via array_keys() function and extract your desired key value then.
see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php